# How to observer base component property

Tags: ember.js

Here is simple code (Ember 1.13.7):

Main component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  classNameBindings: ['isTestCom:test'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.$().on('click', Ember.run.bind(this, function() {
      this._click();
    }));
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.$().off('click');
  },

  _click:function(){
    this.toggleProperty('isTest');
  },
  isTest:false,
  isTestCom: Ember.computed('isTest',function(){
    return this.get('isTest');
  }),
});
```

Extended component:

```
export default MainComponent.extend({
  isTestChiid: Ember.computed('isTestCom',function(){
    console.debug('working');
  })
});
```

The problem is that `isTestChild` never fires. Any idea how to observer mains component properties would be very helpful

Comment: Have you tried accessing `isTestChild` property in the component's template. The function will be called only if CP is accessed.  Let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: you are right... wasn't aware about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `isTestCom` is referenced somewhere (template or javascript code) and it fires a change event, but `isTestChild` isn't then use:

```
export default MainComponent.extend({
  isTestChild: Ember.observer('isTestCom', function() {
    console.debug('working');
  })
});
```

If `isTestChild` is referenced in template code or javascript code then use:

```
export default MainComponent.extend({
  isTestChild: Ember.computed('isTestCom', function() {
    console.debug('working');
  })
});
```

You also mistyped property name, it should be `isTestChild` instead of `isTestChid`.